# Creating Dynamic Pivot Tables using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I’m working on a code to create a dynamic pivot table but I’m struggling as I need the pivot table to read from a dynamic range of data with different column names (Dates) that are changing according to the date ranges.

So for the following line of code:

`Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables( _"PivotTable1").PivotFields("15/01/2016"), "Sum of 15/01/2016", xlSum`

I need to use variable instead of the date `15/01/2017` and I need to use a loop to fill all the date ranges into the data field in the pivot table.

Comment: Please describe the specific problem you're facing and post screenshots/more in-depth code pastes.  Especially with Excel/VBA, it's important to have a strong picture of your question if you want a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific number of dates, you can just replace the hard coded dates with variable names. So in your case with 2 dates :

```
Date1 = "01/01/2017"
Date2 = "05/02/2017"

Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Date1), "Sum of " & Date1 & """, xlSum"
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Date2), "Sum of " & Date2 & """, xlSum"
```

would work.

If you want a loop you can fill the dates to an array like below and loop the values in array with for each loop:

```
Dim Dates(1)
Dates(0) = "01/01/2017"
Dates(1) = "05/02/2017"

For Each Dat In Dates
Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField Worksheets("Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Dat), "Sum of " & Dat & """, xlSum"
Next
```

Comment: The problem is that the dates are dynamic and user can enter date starting from (1/1/2016 - 1/1/2017) and next time he may change the dates to some other range like (20/2/2016 - 117/6/2016 ) so the pivotfields are not specific  dates or names, so instead of Date1 in  Pivotfields(Date1) i want to use cell range for example Range("A1") .i know i cant use pivotfields(Range("A1")) but is there any work around

Comment: You can assign the Excel cell ranges to Variables and use variables in the formula. So Date1 = Range("A1"), Date2 = Range("A2") will do the work for the first solution. For the second array solution it should be Dates(0) = Range("A1"), Dates(1) = Range("A2") and so on.